# org.hibernate.MappingException class not found while looking for property

Tags: java, hibernate, ant, hibernate-mapping, composite-primary-key

Please help me,i really need help...
I create a composite-id in hibernate.Here are things i have

PurchasedTestId.java

```
package jp.go.mhlw.vaccine.draft;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class PurchasedTestId implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long testId;
private Long customerId;

// an easy initializing constructor
public PurchasedTestId(Long testId, Long customerId) {
    this.testId = testId;
    this.customerId = customerId;
}
      // generate setters and getters here
}
```

And here is my vaccin.hbm.xml file

```
<class name="jp.go.mhlw.vaccine.draft.PurchasedTestttt" table="PurchasedTesttt">
        <composite-id name="purchasedTestId" class="jp.go.mhlw.vaccine.draft.PurchasedTestId">
            <key-property name="testId" >
                <column name="testId" ></column>
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="customerId"  column="customerId" />  
        </composite-id>
        <property name="name" column="name" type="string" />
    </class>
```

I am using Ant build (using bulld.xml file) to generate Domain class and DB shema,only class PurchasedTestttt will be generated in my case,I've created the class PurchasedTestId before.
Whenever i start to run tools it throws

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: class jp.go.mhlw.vaccine.draft.PurchasedTestId not found while looking for property: testId
```

But in my vaccin.hbm.xml file i can hold the control key and click on

```
jp.go.mhlw.vaccine.draft.PurchasedTestId
```

And it immediately jumps to PurchasedTestId.java file with same package name.Obviously the PurchasedTestId class is in my classpath.I've been searching alot for 2 days but i could not solve my problem.Please help me figure out what it is.I am so tired
Please help me.

Comment: Has the PurchasedTestId a parameterless constructor? Normally Hibernate needs one... And how does PurchasedTestttt (strange name indeed) look like?

Comment: yes PurchasedTestId also has one default constructor with no argument.The class PurchasedTestttt(domain object) has properties as above vaccin.hbm.xml.This domain object will be generated when i run build.xml file (Ant build).it may be a hibernate bug or i am missing some jars ?

Comment: That is difficult to say without knowing your build process; but being a general hibernate bug is not very probable.

Comment: Thank you so much.now i know what is the problem.In my build.xml file have not included the PurchasedTestId class yet.How can i include this class in build.xml file.I know how to include jars,zip,property and others file type but I failed to include a .java file into build.xml file.

Comment: In vaccine.hbm.xml file has the tag <composite-id name="purchasedTestId" class="jp.go.mhlw.vaccine.draft.PurchasedTestId"> .I doubt that the PurchasedTestId class must be complie into .class file before including this into build.xml file.Am i wrong ? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to specify the **class** of the composite-id in the hbm.xml file; you have to set the **name** of the property in your PurchasedTestttt class. 
E.g. it has to look like:

Class PurchasedTestttt:

```
public class PurchasedTestttt {
    PurchasedTestId purchasedTestId;

    public PurchasedTestId getPurchasedTestId() {
       return purchasedTestId;
    }
    public void setPurchasedTestId(PurchasedTestId purchasedTestId) {
        this.purchasedTestId = purchasedTestId;
    }
    ....
}
```

*.hbm.xml:

```
<class name=”entities.PurchasedTestttt”>
    <composite-id name=”purchasedTestId”>
        <key-property name=”testId” column=”TEST_ID” />
        <key-property name=”customerId” column=”CUSTOMER_ID” />
    </composite-id>
    ...
</class>
```

It is important that the class you use for the composite-id has properties with the same name as specified in *.hbm.xml, but Hibernate does not need to know the class you used for that.

Comment: Thanks very much.if i manually code the PurchasedTestttt.java file it works fine.But what i want to do is using Ant tool along with an hbm.xml file (in my case is build.xml file and vaccine.hbm.xml file) to generate domain classes and Database schema.I have alot of tables so i could not manually code all Domain files one by one. the build.xml works very great when i didnt use composite-id.I want to know how can i include the jp.go.mhlw.vaccine.draft.PurchasedTestId class into class.path of build.xml.Thank you alot for your reply :)

Comment: Then you should perhaps open a new question regarding that ant script (if it is not too large). And I would be happy if you will reward my efforts with a "like" or an accept ;o)

Comment: Yes my friend :) .I marked your reply as right answer.You're a nice helper :).Sorry for my broken english.I will open up a new question :)